# Getting values from jquery GET response

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have been unable to figure this out.

I'm trying to retrieve the price from a input field on the page (from the response) I am requesting

```
$.get('http://site.com', function(data) {
    var div = data;   
    var price = div.getElementById('price').value; 
    alert(price);
});
```

Which leaves me with undefined. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var price = $('#price', div).val();` or `var price = $(div).find('#price').val();`

div is a variable not in the dom, hence dom methods can't apply. You have to first inject it in the dom, or, like in this response, jquery it.

Answer (score -1):

First append the Html in the page, and then try to get the value.

```
$("#some-div").html(data);
var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
```